# Access Spring cloud server from Angular application

Tags: angular, spring-security, spring-cloud

In our microservice architecture, we have an angular front end service that talks to a bunch of back end services though https.

We also have a Spring cloud server setup with some encrypted sensitive properties.

Normally a springboot application would decrypt the content of the config server on the fly.

Is there an out of the box way for Angular to use Spring Cloud Server with Spring security?

Comment: what do you mean by Is there an out of the box way for Angular to use Spring Cloud Server? what protocols your server is using for communication?

Comment: Updated the question. By out of the box I mean if there is a way to use the existing mechanism without ad hoc implementation.